I'm experiencing performance issues when using OFFSET in my SQL queries
For instance, consider the following two queries:
SELECT id, CHARACTER_LENGTH(polygon_data)
FROM polygon_data
LIMIT 10 OFFSET 1;

SELECT id, CHARACTER_LENGTH(polygon_data)
FROM polygon_data
WHERE id = 9;

I noticed that the second query (by specific id) runs much faster than the first one with OFFSET, even though the OFFSET query isn't fetching the skipped rows—it's just returning the 11th row onward.
My expectation was that the query with OFFSET would be faster because it doesn't return the skipped rows, but the database seems to slow down significantly as the offset increases.
Why does using OFFSET cause such a performance hit, even when the skipped rows aren't fetched?
How can I optimize queries that require pagination with large offsets?

' it doesn't return the skipped rows, ' - doesn't it ? https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.4/en/select.html

I've removed the [[tag:database]] as this isn't about database design. I've also gone ahead and removed the conflicting tags; please [edit] your question to (re)tag the actual (R)DBMS you are using. Why does tagging multiple RDBMS products make my question unclear?

Use keyset pagination instead of offset.

Please add an ORDER BY to your query, see: Adding order by with offset and limit in mysql query

We don't know your DBMS. Without an ORDER BY clause, the DBMS is free to read any rows from the table. This should be extremely fast. Your second query though can be even faster, as an index can be used to find the one row that must be read from the table, and then there is only one row to send to the client. Which is faster depends on several factors. A proper LIMIT/OFFSET query will always be slow, as such a query requires an ORDER BY clause, and then the whole table must get sorted in order to know the first eleven rows.

There are many factors that the query performance is depending on, first one is the index so in your case maybe the index of the table is the id column so the second query will be much faster as you don't need to scan all the table and if the id column is not the index, also the second one will be the faster as the first query will need to count the first 10 rows, then it will take the 11th and the higher offset the higher time it will take.
You may do this to improve the first query As I am assuming the id is the index column
SELECT 
    id, CHARACTER_LENGTH(polygon_data)
FROM 
    polygon_data
WHERE
    id > 10
LIMIT 1;

